# How to directly assign HTTP response to an Interface Model type in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataServiceService } from './data-service.service';
import {IModel} from './imodel';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  resultArray:IModel;
  constructor(private dataService:DataServiceService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.dataService.getDataFromURL().subscribe((resultData)=>{
      debugger
      this.resultArray=resultData;
    })
  }
}
```

**dataservice.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataServiceService {

  apiURL='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getDataFromURL(){
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL)
  }


}
```

**imodel.ts**

```
export interface IModel {
       userId: number;
        id: number;
        title: string;
        body: string;
}
```

I have created a Model Interface and trying to fetch data from an API.
I have successfully retrieved the data but i am not able to assign the response to  resultArray which is an IModel type, which shows are error "Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'IModel'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Property 'userId' is missing in type 'Object'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `http.get` method is generic. That means that you can specify the return type like this:

```
getDataFromURL(): Observable<IModel> {
  return this.http.get<IModel>(this.apiURL)
}
```

Read more about typescript [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Comment: I am not agreed with this answer. it did not assign to value in model .if you try to change or delete one property in the model after you can get the same result. no throw exception. Example delete `body: string;` after you get data.no throw the exception. it's wrong